# Hi All, I am disabling a button using "List View Button Layout" option that is present in side bar of the object

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app

I am doing this for so many objects , but i have observed that three objects in my org is not having the option "List View Button Layout" itself. Rest of the objects are having this option. All are custom objects btw Can anyone tell me what might be the reason for this.
PS: I am in lightning environment only.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have created tabs for those objects?

Comment: For one object there is a tab created , but for the other two they are not created

Comment: Even Tab is present you are not able to see List View Button Layout on object manager for that object?

Comment: yes for that object iam not able to see it even though tab is present

Comment: Just to confirm can you check the tab is related to that particular object only? Because I do not see any other reason  for this behaviour

Comment: I have checked it. it is related to that object only. i deleted it and re-created the tab again, now i am able to see the option "List View Button Layout". As the other two objects there are no tabs created the option "List View Button Layout" is disabled. Thanks for your time and help  :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming on it. I will add the same as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to have `List View Button Layout` option on object setup you need to have the Tab for that object. As we need a Tab for any object to see the list views.

As your objects don't have tabs for the two objects because of which you are not able to see `List View Button Layout` for those.